# Well-founded recursion by repeated division

Tags: recursion, idris, induction, totality

Suppose I have some natural numbers *d ≥ 2* and *n > 0*; in this case, I can split off the *d*'s from *n* and get *n = m * d<sup>k</sup>*, where *m* is not divisible by *d*.

[I'd like to use this repeated removal of the *d*-divisible parts as a recursion scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40572811/477476); so I thought I'd make a datatype for the `Steps` leading to *m*:

```
import Data.Nat.DivMod

data Steps: (d : Nat) -> {auto dValid: d `GTE` 2} -> (n : Nat) -> Type where
  Base: (rem: Nat) -> (rem `GT` 0) -> (rem `LT` d) -> (quot : Nat) -> Steps d {dValid} (rem + quot * d)
  Step: Steps d {dValid} n -> Steps d {dValid} (n * d)
```

and write a recursive function that computes the `Steps` for a given pair of `d` and `n`:

```
total lemma: x * y `GT` 0 -> x `GT` 0
lemma {x = Z} LTEZero impossible
lemma {x = Z} (LTESucc _) impossible
lemma {x = (S k)} prf = LTESucc LTEZero

steps : (d : Nat) -> {auto dValid: d `GTE` 2} -> (n : Nat) -> {auto nValid: n `GT` 0} -> Steps d {dValid} n
steps Z {dValid = LTEZero} _ impossible
steps Z {dValid = (LTESucc _)} _ impossible
steps (S d) {dValid} n {nValid} with (divMod n d)
  steps (S d) (q * S d) {nValid} | MkDivMod q Z _ = Step (steps (S d) {dValid} q {nValid = lemma nValid})
  steps (S d) (S rem + q * S d) | MkDivMod q (S rem) remSmall = Base (S rem) (LTESucc LTEZero) remSmall q
```

However, `steps` is not accepted as total since there's no apparent reason why the recursive call is well-founded (there's no structural relationship between `q` and `n`).

But I also have a function

```
total wf : (S x) `LT` (S x) * S (S y)
```

with a boring proof.

Can I use `wf` in the definition of `steps` to explain to Idris that `steps` is total?

Comment: Do you mean `m + d^k`?

Comment: @AndrásKovács: No, I meant that in `m * d^k`, all the `d`'s are in the `d^k` component, so `m` is no longer divisible by `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of using well-founded recursion to do what you're asking. I'm sure though, that there is a better way. In what follows I'm going to use the standard `LT` function, which allows us to achieve our goal, but there some obstacles we will need to work around.

Unfortunately, `LT` is a function, not a type constructor or a data constructor, which means we cannot define an implementation of the 
[`WellFounded`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/17f0899c5ef07d448c3ab2d0ef53abb7fae6fb0a/libs/prelude/Prelude/WellFounded.idr#L33)
typeclass for `LT`. The following code is a workaround for this situation:

```
total
accIndLt : {P : Nat -> Type} ->
         (step : (x : Nat) -> ((y : Nat) -> LT y x -> P y) -> P x) ->
         (z : Nat) -> Accessible LT z -> P z
accIndLt {P} step z (Access f) =
  step z $ \y, lt => accIndLt {P} step y (f y lt)

total
wfIndLt : {P : Nat -> Type} ->
        (step : (x : Nat) -> ((y : Nat) -> LT y x -> P y) -> P x) ->
        (x : Nat) -> P x
wfIndLt step x = accIndLt step x (ltAccessible x)
```

We are going to need some helper lemmas dealing with the less than relation, the lemmas can be found in [this](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/036f0d3543aeaae0e7c9abd7b542d7da) gist (`Order` module). It's a subset of my personal library which I recently started. I'm sure the proofs of the helper lemmas can be minimized, but it wasn't my goal here.

After importing the `Order` module, we can solve the problem (I slightly modified the original code, it's not difficult to change it or write a wrapper to have the original type):

```
total
steps : (n : Nat) -> {auto nValid : 0 `LT` n} -> (d : Nat) -> Steps (S (S d)) n
steps n {nValid} d = wfIndLt {P = P} step n d nValid
  where
    P : (n : Nat) -> Type
    P n = (d : Nat) -> (nV : 0 `LT` n) -> Steps (S (S d)) n

    step : (n : Nat) -> (rec : (q : Nat) -> q `LT` n -> P q) -> P n
    step n rec d nV with (divMod n (S d))
      step (S r + q * S (S d)) rec d nV | (MkDivMod q (S r) prf) =
        Base (S r) (LTESucc LTEZero) prf q
      step (Z + q * S (S d))       rec d nV | (MkDivMod q Z     _) =
        let qGt0 = multLtNonZeroArgumentsLeft nV in
        let lt = multLtSelfRight (S (S d)) qGt0 (LTESucc (LTESucc LTEZero)) in
        Step (rec q lt d qGt0)
```

I modeled `steps` after the [`divMod`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/17f0899c5ef07d448c3ab2d0ef53abb7fae6fb0a/libs/contrib/Data/Nat/DivMod/IteratedSubtraction.idr#L118) function from the [`contrib/Data/Nat/DivMod/IteratedSubtraction.idr`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/17f0899c5ef07d448c3ab2d0ef53abb7fae6fb0a/libs/contrib/Data/Nat/DivMod/IteratedSubtraction.idr) module.

Full code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/52e04e76b0ac8d19a878ce09a152b8f0).

**Warning**: the totality checker (as of Idris 0.99, release version) does *not* accept `steps` as total. It has been recently fixed and works for our problem (I tested it with Idris 0.99-git:17f0899c).